# API Gateway mapping multiple values for a requestParameter key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

Is it possible to pass multiple values to a single request parameter key in integration requests? JSON like or encoded string?

**A typical use case could be passing the `sub` property from the authorizer in the SNS message payload, together with other parameters**

So far I have tried this:

```
integration.request.querystring.Message.foo: method.request.path.foo
integration.request.querystring.Message.bar: method.request.path.bar
integration.request.querystring.Message.userId: context.authorizer.claims.sub
```

But when I make the request via Postman I have this error:

```
"Error": {
    "Code": "MalformedInput",
    "Message": "Start of list found where not expected",
    "Type": "Sender"
},
```

Is this even possible? The docs do not mention it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use mapping templates, I thought they were only for the body.

This is the Apache velocity syntax

```
#set($foo = $input.params('foo'))
#set($userId = $context.authorizer.claims.sub)
$input.json("$")
#set($context.requestOverride.querystring.Message = "{
    ""foo"":  ""$foo"",    
    ""userId"" : ""$userId""
}")"
```

And this is the escaped syntax in SAM template:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  credentials: !GetAtt APIGatewayRole.Arn
  uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish
  requestTemplates:
    application/json: "#set($foo = $input.params('foo'))\n#set($userId = $context.authorizer.claims.sub\
                    )\n$input.json(\"$\")\n#set($context.requestOverride.querystring.Message\
                    \ = \"{\n    \"\"foo\"\":  \"\"$foo\"\",\n    \"\"userId\"\"\
                    : \"\"$userId\"\"\n}\")"
```